# Excel: Calculate number of months in date range, but only for specific year

Tags: excel

My sheet looks like this (sample data)

"Rate" "Begin" "End" 
"1$" "01.01.2011" "01.01.2015"
"2$" "01.06.2012" "01.08.2013"

I want to calculate the number of months for the date ranges which fall in specific years (2012, 2013, 2014) to estimate volume (= months*rate)
For example in the 2nd line I would get 6 months for 2012 (=12$) and 7 months for 2013 (=14$).
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why isn't it 7 months in 2012 - you start on 1st June so including June would give 7. Do you want to count partial months if start date is 10th or 20th for example?

Comment: You are right, it should be 7 months.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your data in A1:C3 then list the years in the header row, e.g. D1 = 2012, E1 = 2013, F1 = 2014 then in D2 use this formula:

`=IFERROR(DATEDIF(MAX($B2,DATE(D$1,1,1)),MIN($C2,DATE(D$1+1,1,1)),"m"),0)*$A2`

format as currency and copy across and down

Assumes you are using Excel 2007 or later and that columns B and C contain valid dates. In earlier Excel versions you can use this alternative formula

`=LOOKUP(99^99,IF({1,0},0,DATEDIF(MAX($B2,DATE(D$1,1,1)),MIN($C2,DATE(D$1+1,1,1)),"m")*$A2))`